# Контроль версий DLL библиотек в Windows

Tags: windows

Подскажите, пожалуйста, способ, с помощью которого можно было бы добавлять версию в DLL библиотеку и однозначно идентифицировать эту версию. Я нашел только 1 способ: это указать при сборке опцию /VERSION. Но она обладает недостатками.
1. Только два числа 1.0, нужно больше.
2. Эту версию можно увидеть только в dumpbin или подобной утилите. И я не смогу ее посмотреть на компьютере, где нельзя поставить такое ПО.

Comment: собираете то в чем? в VS есть возможность указывать нужную версию в формате 0.0.0.0

Comment: Можно хранить в ресурсах, просматривать можно будет в проводнике.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Два числа это `Product Version`. К ним можно добавить `File Version`.
Выше верно было указано, что при сборке в `visual studio` можно в ресурсах `DLL` указать версию в формате `3,10,349,0`.

Подробно, с примером кода можно [посмотреть на msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa381058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Ещё будет полезной ссылка на [корневую статью про версии](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms646981%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).